# Before it works but now it does not work .SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host

Tags: php, email

```
<?php
   require_once('././php_mailer/class.phpmailer.php');
   $mail = new PHPMailer(true); // the true param means it will throw exceptions on errors, which we need to catch

   $mail->IsSMTP(); // telling the class to use SMTP

   try {
       $mail->Host       = 'tls://mail.sipradi.com.np'; // SMTP server
        $mail->SMTPDebug  = 2;                     // enables SMTP debug information (for testing)
        $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                  // enable SMTP authentication
        $mail->Host       = 'tls://mail.sipradi.com.np'; // sets the SMTP server
        $mail->Port       = 25;                    // set the SMTP port for the GMAIL server
        $mail->Username   = 'user_name'; // SMTP account username
        $mail->Password   = 'pass';        // SMTP account password
        $mail->AddAddress('something@sipradi.com.np', 'Full Name');

        $mail->SetFrom('user_name', '<noreply@sipradi.com.np>');
        $mail->Subject = $subject;
        $mail->AltBody = 'To view the message, please use an HTML compatible email viewer!'; // optional - MsgHTML will create an alternate automatically
        $mail->MsgHTML($message);
        if($mail->Send()){
         echo "Message Sent OK<p></p>\n"; die;
        }else{
         echo 'fail'; die;`
`
        }
    } catch (phpmailerException $e) {
        echo $e->errorMessage(); //Pretty error messages from PHPMailer
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage(); //Boring error messages from anything else!
}
?>
```

Comment: It could mean something changed on your server end.

Comment: If it worked before and it doesn't work now, something has changed. Identify what has changed and you'll fix your problem.

Comment: what may be change? could any one suggest me? It does not show authentication error.

Comment: Who knows? The mail server is responding to SMTP traffic on port 25. Beyond that it's anyone's guess.

Answer (score 0):

1. check password and user name
2. check another settings: port, etc.
3. check header info
4. etc.

   I think the problem is the port setting.

[image: Settings for POP and IMAP access - Office Web Apps]

Comment: The comments section is ideal for debugging tips. Answers should (attempt to) contain the solution to the OP's problem.

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation [`$Host`](http://phpmailer.github.io/PHPMailer/classes/PHPMailer.html#property_Host)

> **$Host**
>   *SMTP hosts.*
>   Either a single hostname or multiple semicolon-delimited hostnames. You can also specify a different port for each host by using this format: [hostname:port] (e.g. "smtp1.example.com:25;smtp2.example.com"). Hosts will be tried in order.

and [`$SMTPSecure`](http://phpmailer.github.io/PHPMailer/classes/PHPMailer.html#property_SMTPSecure)

> **$SMTPSecure**
>   *The secure connection prefix.*
>   Options: "", "ssl" or "tls"

This means, that your SMTP server

```
$mail->Host = 'tls://mail.sipradi.com.np'; // SMTP server
```

should be

```
$mail->Host = 'mail.sipradi.com.np'; // SMTP server
```

If you want to use TLS

```
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
```

and last but not least, you might also try a different port `587`, either by setting

```
$mail->Port = 587;
```

or in the setting for the SMPT server

```
$mail->Host = 'mail.sipradi.com.np:587'; // SMTP server
```